# Event Log C# - Cannot open log Application on machine, Win32 Exception: Access is denied

Tags: c#, event-log, system.diagnostics

I am trying to view the Event Viewer as an operational Dashboard to report on any warnings and errors. I am using C# MVC 5 and I am using system.diagnostics. When I try to call the information on the event viewer I am getting the error:

```
'Cannot open log Application on machine "My Machine name".  Win32 Exception is denied'.
```

I suspect its a permissions issue but whether I amend this on the server or inside my application I am unsure.

My code is below:

```
 EventLog log = new EventLog("Application", "MYSERVERNAME");
        int cutoff = 100;
        var events = new List<EventLogEntry>();

        var WarningsNo = 0;
        var ErrorsNo = 0;

        DTO.Logs LogNo = new DTO.Logs();
        DTO.ErrorDetails e = new DTO.ErrorDetails();
        List<DTO.ErrorDetails> errorDetails = new List<DTO.ErrorDetails>();

        for (int i = log.Entries.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            var next = log.Entries[i];
            events.Add(next);
            if (events.Count == cutoff)
                break;
        }


        return Json(errorDetails, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: the user you're running the application as will need permission to write to the event log on the machine where the log is stored. Are you trying to write to the log on the machine where the code is running, or a different machine?

Comment: Hi, I am running on a different machine.  The objective is to report on different servers.

Comment: You might want to read https://www.loggly.com/ultimate-guide/centralizing-windows-logs/

Comment: I have faced the same issue. I have some questiosns in order to be able to help.
Are you in the same Domain of those remote machines? Can you connect to their event logs using the Event Viewer "Connecto to another machine" option?
If that so, it's whith same user? Where are you hosting the MVC application? IIS? If that so, Which Application Pool is using that MVC Application?